# Unable to make a call from Service

Tags: java, android

The app needs to make the phone dial outbound, attaching some DTMF tones to it. This phone call will happen periodically, and needs to start the background service on reboot, or main activity start (the latter is mostly debugging). I have every permission under the sun attached, but I still can't make this happen.

Background: the phone is being used as a remote monitor for a cabin (+ADK board), sending me data I correlate to the attached tones, then hanging up.

- The particular version of Android is 2.3.6, on a pre-paid ATT Fusion 2.
- I have seen a few tickets which say it's possible to send DTMF tones initially - but not during - the call. This is fine. *I'm not exactly sure what the difference would be.*
- It's been a long time since I programmed for Android, so take it easy on me.

The error I receive is:

```
06-05 14:42:41.019: W/ActivityManager(195): Unable to start service Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx-xxx-xxxx flg=0x10000004 }: not found
```

*CallServiceReceiever:*

```
public class CallServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, CallService.class);
        context.startService(service);
    }
}
```

*CallService:*

```
public class CallService extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        String number = "XXX-XXX-XXXX"; // US phone number
        String tones = "1234*5678*9*1234#";

        Log.i("wtf", "Dialing: " + mumber);
        Log.i("wtf", "Append tones: " + tones);

        call.setData(Uri.parse("tel://" + number + "," + tones));
        call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);

        this.getBaseContext().startService(call);

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        CallService getService() {
            return CallService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

First, I tried invoking the call from the Activity 20 seconds after it started (it will be repeating, but I set the flag to "0" for now).

*StartFromActivity:*

```
public class StartFromActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) this.getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent callServiceIntent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), CallServiceReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingCallServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getBaseContext(), 0, callServiceIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar callServiceStart = Calendar.getInstance();
        callServiceStart.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                callServiceStart.getTimeInMillis(), 0, pendingCallServiceIntent);

    }
}
```

Then, I tried invoking the call from a Service  20 seconds after start (it will be repeating, but I set the flag to "0" for now).

*OnRestartReceiver:*

```
public class OnRestartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) this.getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent callServiceIntent = new Intent(this.getBaseContext(), CallServiceReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingCallServiceIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getBaseContext(), 0, callServiceIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Calendar callServiceStart = Calendar.getInstance();
        callServiceStart.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                callServiceStart.getTimeInMillis(), 0, pendingCallServiceIntent);

    }
}
```

The manifest looks like:

```
<application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".StartFromActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
                android:name=".OnRestartReceiver"
                android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".CallServiceReceiver"/>

        <service android:name=".CallService"/>

    </application>
```

Does anybody have insight into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The app needs to make the phone dial outbound, attaching some DTMF tones to it.

AFAIK, that's not possible.

> The error I receive is

The error indicates that you have no `Service` that matches the `Intent`. That is because you are trying to use `ACTION_CALL` with `startService()`, which is not possible. You are welcome to use `startActivity()` with an `ACTION_CALL` `Intent`, assuming that you hold the `CALL_PHONE` permission.

Comment: Are you sure? https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1428


I see this in the ticket comment thread:

You can actually send DTMF tones by invoking   

Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",Uri.parse("tel://" + number));  

context.startActivity(i);

I have used this method as a workaround and it works for my Telcom application.

Using commas "," will send two second delays between tones.

Comment: @FrankLoVecchio: "Are you sure?" -- if it works for your one device, great. I would not assume that all devices and OS versions necessarily support it.

Comment: I would not assume so either :) I will update the code and try, though. Thanks!